# Polymer and page.js wildcards in routes

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, page.js

Am using the polymer starting kit and am trying to access routes to users that does not necessary have a link to it on the page.

routing.html:

```
page('/users/:name', function(data) {
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
});
```

On the page i have:

```
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Addy">Addy</a><br>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Rob">Rob</a><br>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Chuck">Chuck</a><br>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}users/Sam">Sam</a>
```

It is matching the 4 users with the specified urls correct, but i want the route to match any name even tho there is no link to the page.

It will work with the route '/users/*' that will match everything, but i do not want to use that if i dont have to.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: i want to be able to go to a url that match /users/whatever, and it should load the user-info page with the whatever parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That route you have there will achieve what you want. The way page.js uses the `:` character is as an identifier that what follows after this should be treated as a parameter. Lets say we have the following route:

```
page('/users/:name', function(data) {
 app.route = 'user-info';
 app.params = data.params;
});
```

With that we can match the following urls:

```
/users/Addy
/users/Chuck
/users/somebody
```

The `:name` part of the route can be whatever we want and it will be matched.
To know what the `:name` part is on your polymer code you need to get it from the function that we specified when we defined the route. The `data` parameter that is passed on the function contains that info.

On the route we have defined here, we can access the `:name` parameter with `data.params.name` inside the route definition.

```
page('/users/:name', function( data ){
  //We have access to the :name parameter here
});
```

Best way to let the elements that want the data to know what it is. Is to set your `:name` parameter to a variable on your `app` object.

```
page('/users/:name', function( data ){
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
});
```

That code sets the whole parameter data to a variable on your `app` object. In this case we want to access the `:name` parameter. The way we go about it is to pass the `app.params` object to the element that needs that data and access the `:name` parameter with `params.name`, that assumes that you have named the element property in whic you use it `params`.

```
<custom-elem params="{{params}}></custom-elem>
```

Expecting that element to be child element of the `<template is="dom-bind" id="app">` element.

With that in mind we can go to any route that matches the route so `/users/anything` and if you have set up your user page properly you will see the info for the user in this case info for `anything` user.

You can read more about routing with page.js here: [Visionmedia Page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)

---

To solve the issue from coming from outside the current site use following code.

```
var users = function(data){
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
};
page('/users/:name', users);
page('//users/:name', users);
```

It isn't the most elegant thing but will solve the issue. It will cause ugly urls that have two slashes.

---

Better way to solve the second problem.
Don't us the `hashbangs: true` option set it `false`. Instead set the base url to this: `page.base('/#');` That solves the problem and removes the annoiyng `!` from the url. :)

Comment: I beleve my problem is a bit different than what i thought, i have the same problem as in this issue: https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/issues/337 and here https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/issues/292. If i prevent it from redirecting with the 404 and then refreshes then it will actually load correct. It seems like it is only when i manually write in the url in the address bar it will not match the route.

Comment: Oh, that issue. I had that issue myself and I solved it by making a duplicate routes for each route so one with '/users' and other as '//users'. Note the two slashes. That may solve the issue. I'll add that to the answer above.